Transforming a Constrained Functional Optimization Problem into an Unconstrained One for Numerical Solutions
I'm working on a functional optimization problem defined as follows:
Minimize the functional
$$J(x, y) = \int_{0}^{1} \left( x(s)^2 + y(s)^2 \right) \, ds$$
subject to the boundary conditions
$$x(0) = 0, \quad x(1) = 1,$$
and the differential constraint
$$y(s) = x'(s).$$
One straightforward approach is to substitute $y$ directly into $J$, thereby reducing the problem to a functional that depends solely on $x$. Another method involves using Lagrange multipliers to incorporate the differential constraint into $J$, leading to a essentially the same system of equations.
My question is: Is there a method to transform this constrained optimization problem into an unconstrained one? Such a transformation would be highly beneficial for numerically solving the system.
Any insights, methodologies, or references related to this approach would be greatly appreciated!

I am no expert in functional optimization, but maybe a good starting point is to write down the functional derivative $\frac{\partial J[x]}{\partial x}$ according to this definition and insert your particular functional into this definition?
